# Passing NULL to enum type input parameter - C++

Tags: c++, enums, null, parameter-passing

In my code, I have two enums like below:

```
enum myEnum{e1, e2};
enum myEnum2{e3, e4};
```

I have a function prototype like below:

```
void function myFunc(myEnum in_enum1, myEnum in_enum2){

    some-code-here;

}
```

In some condition, I have to leave empty the second input parameter in_enum2.

I tried passing NULL to it, but compiler gave parameter initialization error when doing so.

How can I pass NULL to an enum type input parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums underlying type is ussually `int`, they are not pointers so they can not be null.

You could either use pointers to your enum, or add a NULL option to your enum. Here is the latter:

```
enum myEnum{NULL, e1, e2};
enum myEnum2{NULL, e3, e4};
```

Then call it with the enum's NULL literals.

```
myFunc(myEnum::NULL, myEnum2::NULL);
```

Comment: That depends on how the macro NULL is defined. If it is defined as `0`, then it can be implicitly converted to an (unscoped) enum.

Comment: Good point then I suggest changing from `myEnum::NULL` to `myEnum::null`